# PHP Session Array empty but have counts

Tags: php, html, arrays, session

So I'm trying to pass my radio buttons value to another page using session arrays, unfortunately the session array comes with an empty value though it still shows the array counts it just returns a blank value.

Here is my code in html form

Top:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
{
session_start();
}
?>
```

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="page1.php">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Info</th>
  <th>Yes</th> 
  <th>No</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Fullname" value="Full Name"></td> //yes
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Fullname" ></td>                 //no
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Address" value="Address"></td>  //yes
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Address"></td>                  //no
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Age</td>
 <td> <input type="radio" name="Age" value="Age"></td>          //yes
 <td> <input type="radio" name="Age"></td>                      //no
</tr>
 </table>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['Fullname']) && ($_POST['Address']) && ($_POST['Age'])){
$Fullname = $_POST['Fullname'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$Age = $_POST['Age'];    
}
$info = array($Fullname, $Address, $Age);
$_SESSION['Info'] = $info;

?>
```

and here is my code for page2.php

above html of page2

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
{
session_start();
}
```

inside html

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['Info']) && is_array($_SESSION['Info'])) {
foreach($_SESSION['Info'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

So, what i'm really trying to do is when the user choose "yes" radio button the value of it will be push to an array. For instance, the user choose yes for Name and Address then no for Age, then on the page2.php Name and Address will be displayed. Anything that the user choose as yes will be displayed through array. But somehow with my code it only displays the count and not the actual value of the radio button.

or is there any alternative idea for this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of doing that. If you follow your approach, then start session in page1.php too on top,

```
 <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
    {
       session_start();
    } ?>
<form method="post" action="page1.php">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Info</th>
  <th>Yes</th> 
  <th>No</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Fullname" value="Full Name"></td> //yes
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Fullname" ></td>                 //no
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Address" value="Address"></td>  //yes
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Address"></td>                  //no
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Age</td>
 <td> <input type="radio" name="Age" value="Age"></td>          //yes
 <td> <input type="radio" name="Age"></td>                      //no
</tr>
 </table>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['Fullname']) && ($_POST['Address']) && ($_POST['Age'])){
$Fullname = $_POST['Fullname'];
$Address = $_POST['Address'];
$Age = $_POST['Age'];    
}
$info = array($Fullname, $Address, $Age);
$_SESSION['Info'] = $info;

?>
```

Keep everything same, once your form is submitted to page1.php itself, it will store the session data in $_SESSION['Info'] array. Go to page2.php, and reload the page. You will see your results like this:

```
The value of $_SESSION['0'] is 'Full Name' 
The value of $_SESSION['1'] is 'Address' 
The value of $_SESSION['2'] is 'Age'
```

Also, you can use page2.php in your form action and store the session their as well. :)

Comment: Ohh sorry. I forgot to include it above but there's already a session start on top of my page1. Sorry, gonna edit it now :)

Comment: Can you share the output you are getting in page2.php? As the current code is working fine for me. You just need to make sure the session array is set properly, and each page has the session_start() on top wherever you want to display the session data.

Comment: The value of $_SESSION['0'] is ''
The value of $_SESSION['1'] is ''
The value of $_SESSION['2'] is '' it's like this one

Comment: Oh, that's because you have used $key in page2.php to print, that's called $key=>$value pair. Where $key will store the array index and $value has the real value. Use $value like this "echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$value."'".'] is:". Then you will see value like "The value of $_SESSION['Full Name'] is 'Full Name' "

Comment: @Mahmudul Hassan: is true!

Answer (score 0):

Try to shorten your code this way below.

Use your html form submission, then.

**page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Fullname'], $_POST['Address'], $_POST['Age'])){
    $_SESSION['Info'] = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
}
?>
```

**insidehtml.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Info']) && is_array($_SESSION['Info'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['Info'] as $key => $value){
        echo 'The value of ['.$key.'] is ('.$value.') <br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Answer: maybe that you are missing some html code in your snippet... try with my changes... radio inputs need to have different values... in your snippet assign the value Fullname but at second input radio you miss a value, the same you have done for Address and Age... other issue... you are storing into SESSION without starting session_start(); I figure out what you want obtain from your code and I reworked my answer, it's more bit complex but works fine as you expected:

```
<?php if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start(); } ?>
<form method="post" action="page1.php">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <th>Info</th>
  <th>Yes</th>
  <th>No</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Fullname" value="yes">Yes</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Fullname" value="no">No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Address" value="yes">Yes</td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="Address" value="no">No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Age</td>
 <td> <input type="radio" name="Age" value="yes">Yes</td>
 <td> <input type="radio" name="Age" value="no">No</td>
</tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Fullname']) && isset($_POST['Address']) && isset($_POST['Age'])) {
  if ($_POST['Fullname'] == "yes") {
    $Fullname = array("Fullname" => "Yes");
  } elseif ($_POST['Fullname'] == "no") {
    $Fullname = array("Fullname" => "No");
  }
  if ($_POST['Address'] == "yes") {
    $Address = array("Address" => "Yes");
  } elseif ($_POST['Address'] == "no") {
    $Address = array("Address" => "No");
  }
  if ($_POST['Age'] == "yes") {
    $Age = array("Age" => "Yes");
  } elseif ($_POST['Age'] == "no") {
    $Age = array("Age" => "No");
  }
} elseif (!isset($_POST['Fullname']) || !isset($_POST['Address']) || !isset($_POST['Age'])) {
  $Fullname = array("Fullname" => "Not Set");
  $Address = array("Address" => "Not Set");
  $Age = array("Age" => "Not Set");
}
$info = array($Fullname, $Address, $Age);
$_SESSION['Info'] = $info;
?>
```

insidehtml.php

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['Info']) && is_array($_SESSION['Info'])) {
  foreach($_SESSION['Info'][0] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION[' . "'" . $key . "'" . '] is ' . "'" . $value . "'" . ' <br />';
  }
  foreach($_SESSION['Info'][1] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION[' . "'" . $key . "'" . '] is ' . "'" . $value . "'" . ' <br />';
  }
  foreach($_SESSION['Info'][2] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION[' . "'" . $key . "'" . '] is ' . "'" . $value . "'" . ' <br />';
  }
}
?>
```

[image: another example]

Let's me know if it's what you are looking for... ;-)

Comment: This is what you wanted? If yes please upvote my answer.